# Can JavaScript ignore preflight request when running on browsers?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, httprequest

### Background

I'm consuming an API that is not mine. To do that, I need a **key-code** that user John Doe defines on *page A*. Jane Doe then runs a process on *Page B* that triggers a PHP Script (with GuzzleHttp) to make the API Request using the **Key Code**. Recent problems/changes:

- Sometimes John Doe sets the key code wrongly [1]
- Page A will now need data from the API. [2]

Although the very existence of #2 will solve #1, I still need to solve #2.

### Problem

When John Doe fills the **Key Code** field, I'm trying to make an API call from JavaScript to test if the server accepts the key and gives me the *Key Owner Name* to be stored with the **Key Code**. The key code is given to the server through **Request Headers**. When JS makes the call, the OPTIONS request fails with a 405 (Method not Allowed).

### Conclusion

With GuzzleHttp I can make a GET request to the API without any problems, but when trying the same thing from JS running inside the browser, the OPTIONS request happens and fails. Since I don't own the API, I can't change it to start handling OPTIONS requests, hence the title's question.

- Can I explicitly tell JS to not perform the OPTIONS request even though I need to set a Request Header called `keycode`?
- If not, my only option here is to make an async Ajax call from JS to my server and have PHP make a sync request to the API (having 2 requests be made, increasing wait time)?

### Edit

JS Code:

```
    var data = null;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    });

    xhr.open("GET", "API URL");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("keycode", "CODE-HERE");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    xhr.send(data);
```

Error Message

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://#api-url#. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '#my-domain-here#' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Comment: JavaScript isn't even involved in the OPTIONS preflight. Most likely the reason you could do it with GuzzleHttp is simply that GuzzleHttp isn't subject to the SOP. *"The key code is given to the server through Request Headers."* Sounds like you may need to add a header to the XHR

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Whenever I set the keycode in the XHR header, `OPTIONS` happens and fails.

Comment: @charlietfl My goal here is exactly to find out if that's my only choice.

Comment: not all API's are CORS enabled...and OPTIONS is part of CORS spec. Also you will find `jsonp` as a suggested alternative to try...but no headers can be sent so that won't work

Comment: Options request is sent as part of CORS communication. There are exceptions to it. For example, Post requests with application/x-www-form-urlencoded payload should not trigger pre-flight. Now, the key question here is why this 3rd party service is not accepting your requests, because it is all configurable on the server (that is, accepted request types).